Change of variable in the Besov norm
Assume that it is true for $t =1, $
I wonder how the change of variable leads to the following estimate :

where:

$B^{sq}_r$ is the Besov space defined using the dyadic decomposition. Let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb R^n)$ be such
$ {\rm supp}(\varphi) \subseteq \left\{x; \,  \frac 12<  |x| < 2\right\}$ and denote
$$\varphi_j(x) = \varphi\left(2^{-j}x\right)\quad\text{for} \quad j\in \mathbb N^\ast\quad \text{and}\quad \varphi_0 = 1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty \varphi_j.$$
$$B^{sq}_r:=  \left\{ v \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^n);\,\,  \|v\|_{B^{sq}_r} := \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty 2^{js q} \left\| \mathfrak{F}^{-1} (\varphi_j \hat v)\right\|_r^q  \right)^{\frac 1q} <\infty \right\}.$$
$1<p \leq 2$,  $\frac 1p + \frac{1}{p'} =1$ and $\delta := \frac 1p - \frac 12.$
$t>0.$
$y\mapsto P(y)$ is real valued, $C^\infty$  for $y\neq 0$ and homogeneous of degree 1 ($P(ty) = tP(y)$).
$\mathfrak{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform.

My attempt: The change of variable $t y\to y$ gives
$$\mathfrak{F}^{-1}\left( \frac{\sin tP}{P} \hat v\right)(x)= t^{1-n}\,\mathfrak{F}^{-1}\left( \frac{\sin P}{P} \hat v(t^{-1}\cdot)\right)(t^{-1} x)$$
which leads to the question :
What is $\|u(t^{-1}\cdot)\|_{B^{02}_{p'}}$ in terms of $\|u\|_{B^{02}_{p'}}$.
I asked that question before for this purpose. There are some results in the literature where we can find estimates in Besov norm for a scaled function in terms of the norm of the non-sacaled function, but for very special cases for the scaling parameter $t$ and the smoothing index $s.$ The closest case to the OP is  $t\geq 1$ and $s>0$.
Thank you for any hint.
